# Line break after every 20th number in Java (for-loop)

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers, line-breaks

I am trying to write a program, which shows numbers 1 to 100. I would like to have a line break after every 20th number. I have tried using a counterloop, which resets itself after every 20th number, but the program runs infinite. How do I fix this?

```
public class zahlen1_bis_100 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
            for (int counter = 1;counter <= 20; counter++) {

                    if (counter == 20) {

                        System.out.println();
                        counter = 1;
                    }
                }
             System.out.print(x + " ");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hint: remove the inner loop (just the `for` statement) (option `x % 20`  will be zero every 20th number - if x is divisible by 20)

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I used it in creation a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
                 System.out.print(x + 
                         (x % 20 == 0 ? "\n" : " ")
                             );
                 
                }

            }
```

Inside the print, it prints `x` and then checks if the `x` is a multiple of 20 to print a new line; Otherwise prints a space. It's in `Ternary Operator` format, but could also be written in normal if block format:

```
            for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
                
                System.out.print(x);
                
                if (x % 20 == 0) 
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else
                    System.out.println();
                 
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thank your for help. Now I know about the Ternary Operator format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using an inner loop. Instead of that, you can implement a if statement to break into next line.

Logic => if the number is a multiple of 20, then break into next line.

Implementation =>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        if(x%20==0){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Output =>

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! I wanted to create a "unified" look of the output , so I ended up with the following code:

```
public class zahlen1_bis_100 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {


            if (x < 10) {
                System.out.print(x + "  ");

            } else {
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            }
            if (x % 20 ==0) {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }


    }
}
[Result][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66tXZ.png
```

Comment: @user16320675 that would be a very useful answer for you to post for everyone.

Comment: Hey Jacob, your answer can be improved if you explain what you learned (original code was looping the counter instead of just incrementing it once per iteration), and dont forget to select an answer as solving the question.